# How to make a in-text citation number an italic (or emphasized) using the following MWE using thebibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, acm

[Overleaf link is attached.](https://www.overleaf.com/project/5d700103895b410001a8ba59)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\renewcommand\citeleft{(}
\renewcommand\citeright{)}

\begin{document}

This is a test document~\cite{prise}.  **Question: If I use \emph{\cite{}} both parenthesis and citation numbers becomes emphasized. I just want to make a number italic not the parenthesis. Could anyone help me?**

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{prise} Prise KM, O'sullivan JM. Radiation-induced bystander signalling in cancer therapy. Nature Reviews Cancer 2009; 9:351.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The Overleaf link is restricted. Also, [please don't add Overleaf MWEs](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8402/adding-an-overleaf-link-as-well-instead-of-mwe).

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Did you get a chance to look at my problem?

Comment: Looking at it now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the parentheses to be upright using the command `\textup`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\renewcommand\citeleft{\textup{(}}
\renewcommand\citeright{\textup{)}}

\begin{document}

This is a test document~\cite{prise}.  **Question: If I use \emph{\cite{prise}} both parenthesis and citation numbers becomes emphasized. I just want to make a number italic not the parenthesis. Could anyone help me?**

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{prise} Prise KM, O'sullivan JM. Radiation-induced bystander signalling in cancer therapy. Nature Reviews Cancer 2009; 9:351.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Finally, \renewcommand\citeleft{(\textit}
\renewcommand\citeright{\textit)} worked for me. Thank you for your idea though.

Comment: @AshokTiwari that seems a bit odd, if I try that I get ( *1 )*, i.e., the first parenthesis is upright and the second is italic.

Comment: \renewcommand\citeleft{(\textit}
\renewcommand\citeright{\textup{)}} is the right one. Sorry about that.